# $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \cos^2(\pi \sqrt[\leftroot{-2} \uproot{1} 3]{n^3+n^2+2n}), \space n \in N$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos^2(\pi \sqrt[\leftroot{-2} \uproot{1} 3]{n^3+n^2+2n}), \space n \in N$$

I think that the expression under the root will resolve into a $(n+a)^3$ term, which means that the limit will eventually be of the form $\cos^2(n\pi +a\pi)$, which is solvable. However, I am unable to follow through with this strategy. Any hints/helps are appreciated!

Comment: This theme has certainly appeared earlier on our site. The occurrence I recall had the square root of a quadratic instead of the cube root of a cubic but the idea was the same (and also appears Jean-Claude's +1 answer, more experienced users should IMHO search rather than post, so I'm not upvoting their answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we have

$\forall n>0, \pi\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2+2n}=\pi n\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}$

This shows that: $\pi\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2+2n} \sim \pi n$ ($n\rightarrow +\infty$)

Hence the idea of adding and subtracting $\pi n$ in the Cosine:

$\cos^2\left(\pi n\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}\right)=\cos^2\left(\left(\pi n\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}-\pi n\right)+\pi n\right)$

$=\cos^2\left(\pi n \left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}-1\right)+\pi n\right)$

$=\cos^2\left(\pi n \left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}-1\right)\right)$

($(-1)^n$ appears but disappears thanks to the square)

However

$\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}-1=\frac{1}{3n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$

The limit is equal to $\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=\frac14$

Note: To conclude we can use the limit

$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{1+h}-1}{h}=\frac{1}{3}$

(derivative of $x\mapsto \sqrt[3]{1+x}$ at 0)

Then

$\pi n\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}-1\right)=\left(\pi+\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}}$

Comment: Great answer, appreciate the $(-1)^n$ disappearing explanation. Why do you (and the other answers) represent the expansion with $o(\frac 1n)$? I haven’t come across that terminology before.

Comment: Thank you. This corresponds to the little-o notation and it represents an expression of the form 1/n multiplied by something that tends to 0, but you can also use the big-O notation. If you have never heard of Taylor series or asymptotic expansion, then to conclude you need to determine the limit directly.

Answer (score 2):

$$L=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \cos^2(\pi \sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2+2n} = \cos^2 (n\pi [1+1/n+2/n^2]^{1/3}- 1])$$ $$\implies L= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\cos^2 n\pi[1/(3n)+2/(3n^2)+...]=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \cos^2 (\pi/3+O(1/n))]=\frac{1}{4}.$$
In above we have used $\cos^2 (x-n\pi)=\cos^2x$ and  $(1+h)^{\nu}=1+\nu h+O(h^2)$ if $|h|<<1.$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the cubic root using the binomial expansion  at order $1$:
$$n\biggl(1+\frac 1n+\frac 2{n^2}\biggr)^{\!\rlap{1/3}}= n\biggl(1+\frac1{3n} +o\Bigl(\frac1n\Bigr)\biggr)=n+\frac13+o(1)$$
and do some trigonometry: 
\begin{align}
\cos^2(\pi \sqrt[\leftroot{2} \uproot{1} 3]{n^3+n^2+2n})&=\cos^2\Bigl(n\pi+\frac\pi3+o(1)\Bigr)=\frac{1+\cos\bigl(2\pi+\frac{2\pi}3+o(1)\bigr)}{2}=\frac{1+\cos\bigl(\frac{2\pi}3+o(1)\bigr)}{2}\\
&\to\frac{1+\cos\bigl(\frac{2\pi}3\bigr)}2=\frac14.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

It could be interesting to make the problem more general considering
$$\cos^2(\pi \sqrt[3]{n^3+an^2+bn})=\frac 12\left(1+\cos(2\pi \sqrt[3]{n^3+an^2+bn})\right)$$

Now, using the binomial expansion or Taylor expansion
$$\sqrt[3]{n^3+an^2+bn}=n+\frac{a}{3}-\frac{a^2-3 b}{9 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ making
$$\cos\left(2\pi \sqrt[3]{n^3+an^2+bn}\right)=\cos\left(2n\pi+\frac{2\pi a}{3}-\frac{2\pi(a^2-3 b)}{9 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$$ that is to say
$$\cos\left(\frac{2\pi a}{3}-\frac{2\pi(a^2-3 b)}{9 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)=\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  a}{3}\right)+\frac{2 \pi  \left(a^2-3 b\right) }{9 n}\sin
   \left(\frac{2 \pi  a}{3}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ So, for the whole expression
$$\frac 12\left(1+\cos(2\pi \sqrt[3]{n^3+an^2+bn})\right)=\frac 12\left(1+\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  a}{3}\right)+\frac{2 \pi  \left(a^2-3 b\right) }{9 n}\sin
   \left(\frac{2 \pi  a}{3}\right)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

**Edit**

The above shows that the case where $b=\frac {a^2} 3$ is particular. If wa want to see how is the limit  is approached, we need one ore term in the expansion to get
$$\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  a}{3}\right)\right)+\frac{\pi  a^3 }{81 n^2}\sin
   \left(\frac{2 \pi  a}{3}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$